# can't create your crontab file in the crontab directory

Tags: cron, solaris

OS: Solaris 5.11

Until today, I was able to populate the crontab using:

```
crontab myjobs.dat
```

In fact, I have a shell script that executes this so that I can refresh crontab. I've also used `echo > crontab` to "delete" all entries.

But today, I get the following error whether I use `crontab -e` and attempt to save an entry or using `crontab {filename}`.

```
crontab: can't create your crontab file in the crontab directory.
```

The `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` perms are unchanged from before.

I'm able to perform `crontab` edits in another host (a clone) without any errors.

Is the problem actually within the crontabs directory?

Any insights are appreciated!

Comment: Did you change permissions accidentally on the `crontab` executable?  If you did, chances are that you've managed to also change permissions on _other_ executables. You may want to look into that.

Comment: Did you or anyone else change the permissions on **any** executables?  There are a lot of "security" instructions out there telling you to remove certain permissions to make the OS "more secure" - and those mis-"guides" can break Solaris in ways just like this.  Also, run `df -h` to see if you have any full filesystems.

Comment: /bin/crontab has 555 perms.

Comment: df -h /var shows plenty of disk available.

Comment: @AJCafe `/bin/crontab` should have `-r-sr-xr-x` permissions, not `r-xr-xr-x`, and be owned by `root:bin`.  Somebody who didn't know what they were doing broke your system.  If you have some "security" person pushing you to do things like remove setuid permissions on parts of the operating system, you just saw what that advice does.  And if you're paying Oracle for Solaris support, tell that "security" person that you're not going to violate your Oracle support contract by making unsupported modifications to core operating system components.